# Exact definition of time correlation function

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-analysis

Given a stochastic process $X(t)\in \Omega=\mathbb{R}$, markovian, ergodic and with a unique stationary distribution (e.g. a Boltzmann distribution), the time correlation function is usually defined by the relation:
$$
C(t) = \langle X(0) X(t) \rangle
$$

If I am right the angle brackets indicate an expected value, so we could rewrite the same relation as:
$$
C(t) = \mathrm{E}_P  [X(0) X(t)] = \int_\mathrm{\Omega} X_0(\omega) X_t(\omega) dP(\omega) 
$$

where $P$ is the probability measure of the process.

I know that the expected value of a random variable $X$ is defined as:
$$
\mathrm{E}_P[X] = \int_\Omega X(\omega) dP(\omega) = \int_\mathbb{R} x \mu(x)dx 
$$

where $\mu(x)$ is the probability density function.

First of all I have the following "sub"questions:

1. If $X(0)=x_0 \in \mathbb R$, is it correct to write the following?

$$
\mathrm{E}_{P^{x_0,0}}[X(0)] = \int_\Omega x_0(\omega) dP^{x_0,0}  = \int_\mathbb R  x \delta(x-x_0) dx = x_0 
$$

where $P^{x_0,0}$ is the probability distribution at time $t=0$ of the process starting at point $x_0$. In my opinion, this corresponds to the Dirac delta, because in the beginning the probability distribution is concentrated in a point, right?

2. Let's now consider the process  $X(t)$ when $t>0$, is it correct to write the following?
   $$
   \mathrm{E}_{P^{x_0,t}}[X(t)] = \int_\mathbb R  x \mu_{x_0,t}(x) dx 
   $$

where $\mu_{x_0,t}(x)$ is the density function at time $t>0$ of the process starting at point $x_0$, but when the process is not stationary yet.
Note that this definition becomes the following for $t\rightarrow \infty$:

$$
\mathrm{E}_P[X(t)] = \int_\mathbb R  x \pi(x) dx 
$$

where $\pi(x)$ is the stationary distribution.

3. Finally I have the original question. "Merging" the two previous definitions (assuming that they are right), is it correct to write the time correlation function  as follows?

$$
C(t) = \mathrm{E}_P  [X(0) X(t)] = \int_\mathbb{R} x \delta(x-x_0) \int_\mathbb{R} y \mu_{x_0,t}(y) dy dx 
$$

Comment: $ \int_\mathrm{R} x \delta(x-x_0) \int_\mathrm{R} y \mu_{x_0,t}(y) dy dx  = x_0 \int_\mathrm{R} y \mu_{x_0,t}(y) dy$ since $\int_\mathrm{R} f(x) \delta(x-x_0) = f(x_0)$ (if it is continuous, otherwise $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0-h)+f(x_0+h)}{2}$)

Comment: You may easily check the definition of correlation online (I assume you are meaning those ordinary (auto-)correlation). The definition here only applied to normalized random variables with mean 0 and variance 1 (I guess they are presumed in previous context). And in particular, when one of the random variable is a constant, the covariance (and thus the correlation) is 0.

Comment: All the definitions that I found use either the angle brackets or the expected value. But I cannot find an explicit definition (i.e. using the integrals).